# How to remove newline character pr line break within a column in a csv file?

Tags: csv, text-files, delimited

Is there an easiest way to remove/replace line breaks in csv file? Many thanks!

Comment: Please provides more information like: language, sample code?

Comment: I have extracted the file using ssis, and i will upload it to salesforce. i noticed that there are line breaks. Note that i already removed it in ssis